# SharePoint Lookup column on a Person column in a different list

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have 2 SharePoint lists. One list will be a list of employees that are required to perform a specific function. In this list, there will be a column type of Person that pulls from AD.

The 2nd list will be the data entry list; I want to have a lookup column in this list that references the Person column in the 1st list, but when I attempt to create the column, it is not showing the Person column from the 1st list as an option to select.

The intent is so that when users attempt to add a record in the 2nd list that they're only selecting employees that have been pre-defined in the 1st vs having to search AD.

Is it not possible to have a lookup column in one list reference a Person column in another?

Comment: Not sure if it is possible, but, have you searched about it? - if so, post the references link of your research. Also, check if there are posts related to your issue in https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I have - most of what I find is related to older versions of SharePoint, and not SharePoint Online. I did some initial searching on stackexchange prior to this site, and didn't really find anything there either. I will do some more searching there and see what I can find.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a workaround which you can have a try.

In the first list, create a new single text column named "Employee Name", and hide it from the view to avoid confusion. Add a flow to update this column with the display name of Person & Group field.

Here is an example flow I made to update all items in the list 1. Considering the issue of infinite loop for automatic triggers like `when an item is created/modified`. I used a manual trigger, when the flow runs, it will update all the items in the list. You can change it based on your requirements.

Then in List 2, just create a lookup column for the new "Employee Name" column. Then the job is done.

[image]